# I need IIS Manager rewrite rule to view a page when you are at a different url

Tags: windows, iis, url-rewrite-module

On a windows server.  I want a user to see the page www.example.org/placrun when they go to www.example.org/placestorun, but I want the url to be www.example.org/placestorun. Essential I need the url changed. Any help on this would be great

Comment: If it's so simple why not share?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And I don't want to redirect a url. I want to change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of this feature is "Rewrite". You need to add this rewrite rule to your web.config file:

```
<rule name="Rewrite placestorun">
  <match url="^placestorun$"/>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/placrun"/>
</rule>
```

The regexp `^placestorun$` will match only if you visit URL www.example.org/placestorun and `<action type="Rewrite" url="/placrun"/>` define a result that you want to rewrite it to `placrun` URL

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly